# How do I move the dock to the right of screen on loki?

Tags: release-loki, plank

By default, the dock (plank) sits at the bottom of the screen. I'd like it to be on the right, since my monitor is quite wide, and I want to use as much vertical space as possible for windows.

In previous versions (Freya), I could use elementary Tweaks, but the settings for the dock are not in it in Loki.

Is there a setting I could change if I use dconf Editor?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the plank preferences by doing either <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+right-click on the plank, or from a command line  `plank --preferences`.

Answer (score 5):

Achieve this task by...

1. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+right click anywhere on the dock
2. Select Preferences
3. Select Position drop down box
4. Select desired option

Answer (score 1):

I found it. Using dconf, the settings for plank are in:

`net` > `launchpad` > `plank` > `docks` > `dock1`

I recommend turning on `show-dock-item`, which provides a new dock item that opens the dock settings, where you can change the other settings (like the dock position).

**Edit**: Using dconf Editor is not recommended, but I'll leave my answer here in case anyone wants to know this method for other reasons.